# How to read custom metatags from .wav file?

Tags: python, audio, metadata, audacity

I have been trying to load in Python the custom metatags that were probably added to the .wav files I am dealing with through Audacity or Metadatics. These aren't ID3, and from what I can tell by opening the .wav file in a text editor, they are appended to the end of the .wav file, although they are separated by non-readable characters, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLoqf.png)

With libraries such as mutagen and tinytag I have only been able to read the standard metadata fields. Is there any way to read these in Python or would I have to consider manually parsing them?

Comment: Hey Christos, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show us an example file or explain how to make an equivalent one? What kind of properties are they (from the screenshot it looks like genre perhaps?)

Comment: Unless you can find some third-party module that can parse and return them, you'll have to write the code to do it yourself. I imagine there's some sort of standardized way of adding tags to .wav files that doesn't corrupt them, so knowing how to do that would obviously be very useful.

Comment: Have you checked with [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) to see if it can recognize the metadata?  Use the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) to get names and the group they belong to.